# CFML and Twitter4J (JAVA) Syntax

Tags: coldfusion, twitter4j, coldfusion-10, cfml

I have figured out how to send tweets and how to return the users Home Timeline.
To return the timeline you just do the following :-

```
timeline = t4j.getHomeTimeline();
```

( where t4j is the twitter4j java object )

However in order to automate this ( i.e. call the timeline every 5 mins) i need to pass the last twitter ID to getHomeTimeline.

In the twitter4j JAVA examples there is the following java :-

```
Paging paging = new Paging(2, 40);
List statuses = twitter.getHomeTimeline(paging);
```

so I tried :-

```
timeline = t4j.getHomeTimeline(sid);    throws a method not found or overloaded error
timeline = t4j.getHomeTimeline(1, sid); throws a method not found or overloaded error

sid = JavaCast("long", session.homeTimeline_sid);
timeline = t4j.getHomeTimeline(sid); throws a method not found or overloaded error

timeline = t4j.getHomeTimeline().Paging('sinceID',sid); Again an error
```

Does anyone know the correct syntax for this ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the syntax :-

```
        sid = JavaCast("long", session.homeTimeline_sid);
        tPaging = createObject("java", "twitter4j.Paging");
        tPaging.setSinceId(sid);
        timeline = t4j.getHomeTimeline(tPaging);
```